# Copy from word and paste editor the bullet list formatting is missing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

Tinymce 6 version

I have word document contains some list items like shown below
[image]

After pasting the content in Tinymce editor the formatting is not correct. it's placed as 'paragraph'.

[image: image image]

Expected:
It should keep the formatting: like below
'

- Text 1
- Text 2

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/XXXXXXXXXXX/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#myeditablediv',
    inline: true,
     plugins: 'anchor autolink charmap codesample paste emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table | align lineheight | numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat | paste pastetext',
      paste_word_valid_elements: '-strong/b,-em/i,-u,-span,-p,-ol,-ul,-li,-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-h6,-p/div,-a[href|name],sub,sup,strike,br,del,table[width],tr,td[colspan|rowspan|width],th[colspan|rowspan|width],thead,tfoot,tbody',
      paste_merge_formats: true
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>TinyMCE Inline Editing Mode Guide</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="myeditablediv">Click here to edit!</div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could please help me to how to adopt this word import part only in my code?

They give some suggestion I don't know how to implement this. Any one help me.
[Request for maintainers: word import open source logic #7487](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/discussions/7487)

**FYI:**

Microsoft Word content processing was removed from the open source codebase in TinyMCE 6, sorry. We are now only maintaining our premium powerpaste plugin for word import, although we are open to promoting a community continuation of the TinyMCE 5 word import logic:

[Request for maintainers: word import open source logic #7487](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/discussions/7487)

Thanks